# Python Pandas Group By Error 'Index' object has no attribute 'labels'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting this error:

```
 'Index' object has no attribute 'labels'
```

The traceback looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-23-e0f428cee427>", line 1, in <module>
df_top_f = k.groupby(['features'])['features'].count().unstack('features')

 File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2061, in unstack
return unstack(self, level, fill_value)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape.py", line 405, in unstack
fill_value=fill_value)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape.py", line 90, in __init__
self.lift = 1 if -1 in self.index.labels[self.level] else 0

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'labels'
```

While running the following code

```
df_top_f = df.groupby(['features'])['features'].count().unstack('features')
```

df has the following structure:

```
                                      features
             Ind                              
             0                         Doorman
             1                    Cats Allowed
             2                         Doorman
             3                    Cats Allowed
             4                    Dogs Allowed
             5                         Doorman
```

df.index looks like this:

```
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=267906, step=1, name='Ind')
```

Looks very straight forward, but I can't understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: You can't unstack a single level index... what are you trying to get as output?

Comment: @Mitch Just a count of the number of times each element appears in the features column

Comment: What's wrong with removing `.unstack('features')`. Can you give a _specific_  output format?

Comment: @Mitch Yes I want the output in tabular format with each row having two columns- the row element and its count

By removing unstack I am getting the data in one column

Comment: You can replace `df.groupby(['features'])['features'].count()` with `df['features'].value_counts()`

Comment: @ayhan Yes that's a good suggestion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps not the shortest, but a very straightforward approach would just be to construct a new DataFrame explicitly from the index and values.

```
>>> grp_cnt = df.groupby(['features'])['features'].count()
>>> pd.DataFrame(dict(features=grp_cnt.index, count=grp_cnt.values))

   count      features
0      2  Cats Allowed
1      1  Dogs Allowed
2      3       Doorman
```

Alternatively, you could achieve a one-liner with renaming columns and [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) using

```
>>> df.groupby(['features'])['features'].count().to_frame().rename(
         columns={'features':'counts'}).reset_index()

       features  counts
0  Cats Allowed       2
1  Dogs Allowed       1
2       Doorman       3
```

Your current attempt isn't working because you can't unstack a single level index on a Series to coerce it into a DataFrame.

Comment: @Uasthana You're welcome! I added an alternative too.

Comment: Thank you for the insight and thank you for sharing the  second one it is much easier to understand and remember